# App with Danish payment system Mobile-pay (Swift/Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am currently trying to integrate some Objective-C into a swift app, but keep getting this error when I run the app and tries to tab a row in my UItableview.

I Mobile-pays API and start files and have inserted them in the MobilePaySwiftIntegration-Bridging-Header.h

But I still can´t get it to work :

```html
2015-08-28 21:45:32.138 MobilePaySwiftIntegration[1622:311159] -[__NSCFConstantString urlEncode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bfe5088
2015-08-28 21:45:32.140 MobilePaySwiftIntegration[1622:311159] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString urlEncode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bfe5088'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d716c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010df9ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d71e0ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d67413c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d673cd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MobilePaySwiftIntegration           0x000000010bec3cae -[MobilePayManager beginMobilePaymentWithOrderId:productName:productPrice:productImage:receiptMessage:error:] + 333
    6   MobilePaySwiftIntegration           0x000000010bec3b3e -[MobilePayManager beginMobilePaymentWithOrderId:productPrice:receiptMessage:error:] + 90
    7   MobilePaySwiftIntegration           0x000000010bec2649 -[ProductListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 505
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c1bdd89 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1293
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c1bdeca -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c0f05ec _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c0f0466 _afterCACommitHandler + 533
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d649ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d649c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d63fa33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d63f366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f0f3a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c0cc8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    18  MobilePaySwiftIntegration           0x000000010bec326f main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112b2d145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

My project is on github here
https://github.com/Joachimdj/MobilePaySwiftIntegration

Comment: More details please. On which line does the error occur? Show the relevant code.

Comment: line 8 in main.m   http://thedittman.dk/files/xcodeError.png